# On the road to understanding F-Bounded Polymorphism

Tags: scala, f-bounded-polymorphism

Before even getting  to  F-bounded Polymorphism there is construction that underpin it that i already have a hard  time to understand.

```
trait Container[A]
trait Contained extends Container[Contained]
```

That construction which seem to be a trivial object oriented thing to do as it also exist in java, is already slightly puzzling me.

The issue is that when i see this  `trait Contained extends Container[Contained]` it feels like an infinite type recursion to me.

When we define the type List even tho we have `Cons[A](a:A, tail:List[A])`, we also have `case object Nil`. So the recursion can end with  Nil.

But here, i don't understand how we are not in an infinite recursion ? And why it works.

Can someone care to un-confused me about it ? Or if there is any documentation, blog, or whatever can explain how this works, or maybe is implemented.

Comment: There is no recursion here because there are no values. It just says that `Contained ` is a `Container[Contained]` nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't need to keep expanding to the infinitum.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez For once i am a bit  puzzled by your explanation. Why  do we say that List is a recursive type, there is no value as far as i can tell ..... If not list, well there is exist the  notion of recursive type, do recursive type need value to be recursive, can you  give me an example of a simple recursive type, and show me where the value is involved ?

Comment: Its same as `class A extends Comparable[A]`. What is so confusing about it ? `List` is a recursive data strcuture. Its not actually a recursive type. Its just a data strucutre which recursively uses it self.

Comment: @MaatDeamon `Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A])` I see two values there; `head` & `tail`, one of them is of the same type we are defining thus we say it is a recursive type.

Comment: `trait Contained`, declare the type `Contained`, and in defining it also state that it is a sub-type of `Container[Contained`]. But what is `Container` of `Contained` if `Contained` is not yet defined ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon it was already defined, you can think that the process of defining types have different stages. First we give them a name, then we define if they take other types as parameters, then we define if they have a subtyping relationship with other types and finally we define the operations it provides.

Comment: @sarveshseri just because i have been using it for years, does not mean i theorethically understood it. I just did not care, until now. Beside, i am not arguing against you that it is confusing or not confusing. I'm confused, and i need help to get out of the confusion. I think i explained, why i think it is recursive. If you want to help someone confused, you have first to understand their confusion.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez That start making sense. Would you care please, to write a quick response, that shows, the implicit statement that comes with a declaration such as ```trait Contained extends Container[Contained]```. How does scala technically desconstruct that, i.e. as you put it what are the stage

Comment: I know sub-typing does not exist in haskell, but as i started learning it, to better understand functional scala, you see how, type definition  in haskell is translated in scala. The extends keywords is used to define data constructor. But granted that's ADT, and they  follow a strict pattern in scala. Maybe  that's where i need to be careful.

Comment: @MaatDeamon No idea what is the exact process the compiler uses, I just see it from the intuitive level.

Comment: This is pure sub-type, and what you are saying @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez is that `trait Contained extends Container[Contained]` involved more statement than what i see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237245/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-maatdeamon).

Comment: also asked at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/on-the-road-to-understanding-f-bounded-polymorphism/7802/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your question is driven by confusion about the meaning of the term `recursive type` and the difference between `kind`, `type`, and `class`.

Lets first address the `recursive type`. Sometimes people mis-use `recursive type` to actually mean that this `type` corresponds to a data structure which recursively contains itself.

Following `Tree` is a `recursive data strcuture` but not a `recursive type`,

```scala
trait Tree[+A]

case class NonEmptyNode[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
case object EmptyNode extends Tree[Nothing]
```

Whereas, something like following is not a `recursive data strcuture` but it's a `recursive type`.

```scala
trait Mergeable[+A]

class A(val i: Int) extends Mergeable[A]
```

---

Interestingly, this is also related to the "importance" of some debated features of many modern languages - `null` and `mutability`.

So, lets say you were one of the designers of an Java language (back in early 2000's) and wanted to empower your users by adding support for generic programming.

You expect your users to be able to define generic contracts for their classes. For example, a contract for mergable classes.

```
public abstract class Mergable<A> {
    public A merge(A other)
}
```

Which is perfectly fine. But, this also opens the door for something like following

```
public abstract class HasBrother<A> {
    public A brother;
}

public class Human extends HasBrother<Human> {
    public Human brother;

    public Human(Human brother) {
        this.brother = brother;
    }
}
```

And this is where the problem starts. How will you ever be able to create an instance of `Human` ?

But they had an "awesome" solution for it. Just use `null` and keep the `brother` `mutable` (don't use `final`).

```
Human h1 = new Human(null);
Human h2 = new Human(null);

h1.brother = h2;
h2.brother = h1;
```

But `scala.collection.immutable.List` (and the `Tree` created above) data strcuture in Scala is very similar to this. And we don't like `null` and `mutability`.

This is possible in Scala only due to support for `type parameter variance` and the special `bottom type` called `Nothing`.

---

Now, lets talk about `kind`, `type` and `class`.

`type` can be thought as a defined `contract`.

`class` can be thought as the runtime implementation of the above `contract`.

`kind` is actually a `type` constructor. It needs a `type parameter` to construct the `type`.

Lets take following `List` as an example,

```scala
trait MyList[+A]

class MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]
class MyCons[A](val value: A, val tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
```

Note :: I am intentionally not using `case object` or `case class` to avoid the confusions caused by companion objects.

Here,

`kind` for `MyList` is `F[+A]`.

`kind` for `MyCons` is `F[+A]`.

`kind` for `MyNil` is `A`.

`MyList` has no corresponding `type`, but it has a corresponding class `MyList`.

`MyCons` has no corresponding `type`, but it has a corresponding class `MyCons`.

`MyNil` has a corresponding `type` `MyNil` and a corresponding class `MyNil`.

These corresponding `type` (available at only compile-time in most languages) and `class` (which exist at run-time) are bound to `variables` when they are created.

In `val l: MyCons[Int] = new MyCons(1, new MyNil)`, `l` will have type `MyCons[Int]` and runtime class `MyCons` (which will be an instance of `Class[_ <: MyCons[Int]]`).

But, in `val l: MyList[Int] = new MyCons(1, new MyNil)`, `l` will have type `MyList[Int]` and run-time class `MyCons` (which will be an instance of `Class[_ <: MyList[Int]]`).

---

Now, lets talk about the actual `recursive types`? We said earlier that a recursive type looks like following,

```
trait Mergeable[+A]

class Abc extends Mergeable[Abc]
```

But saying that the above is a recursive type is kind of wrong. It is more accurate to say that `Mergeable` is a `kind` which can result in `recursive` types.

```
val abc: Abc = new Abc
// type - Abc; class - Abc (Class[_ <: Abc])

val abc: Mergeable[Abc] = new Abc
// type - Mergeable[Abc]; class - Abc (Class[_ <: Mergeable[Abc]])

val abc: Mergeable[Mergeable[Abc]] = new Abc
// type - Mergeable[Mergeable[Abc]]; class - Abc (Class[_ <: Mergeable[Mergeable[Abc]]])

// ... and so on to Infinity
```

But, if we remove make that `A` invariant then this `kind` can not result in `recursive types`.

```
trait Mergeable[A]

class Abc extends Mergeable[Abc]

val abc: Abc = new Abc
// type - Abc; class - Abc (Class[_ <: Abc])

val abc: Mergeable[Abc] = new Abc
// type - Mergeable[Abc]; class - Abc (Class[_ <: Abc])

val abc: Mergeable[Mergeable[Abc]] = new Abc
//                                   ^
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : Abc
// required: Mergeable[Mergeable[Abc]]
// Note: Abc <: Mergeable[Abc] (and Abc <: Mergeable[Abc]), but trait Mergeable is invariant in type A.
// You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

---

These `recursive types` are different from `F-Bound polymorphism`.

The following is `F-Bound` but not `recursive`

```scala
trait Fruit[A <: Fruit[A]]

class Apple extends Fruit[Apple]
```

Here, `kind` of `Fruit` is `F[A <: iw$Fruit[A]]`. And we are adding an upper bound on `A` that says `A` has to be `sub-type` of `Fruit[A]` (which is an `F`). This is where the name `F-Bound` comes from.

The following is both `F-Bound` and `recursive`.

```scala
trait Fruit[+A <: Fruit[A]]

class Apple extends Fruit[Apple]
```

Here, `kind` of `Fruit` is `F[+A <: iw$Fruit[A]]`.

Now, I can specify the type of any `Apple` at many recursive depths.

```
val f: Apple = new Apple
// type - Apple; class - Apple (Class[_ <: Apple])

val f: Fruit[Apple] = new Apple
// type - Fruit[Apple]; class - Apple (Class[_ <: Fruit[Apple]])

val f: Fruit[Fruit[Apple]] = new Apple
// type - Fruit[Fruit[Apple]]; class - Apple (Class[_ <: Fruite[Fruit[Apple]]])

// ... and so on to Infinity
```

Any language which does not support `higher kinds` can not have `F-bound types`.

---

Now, we can finally come to your doubt where you are thinking about the infinite loop.

Like we said earlier, a `type` can be thought to be like a `label` used to refer to a certain contract. So, that `eager looping` actually does not happen.

(I think) Scala compiler uses the `implicit evidences` (`=:=`, `<:<` constraints) for type comparisions. These `evidences` are lazily generated by the compiler by using the `type bounds` on `type parameters`. So, the `compiler` has the capabilty of recursilvely generating the `evidences` for `type of any depth` among these `recursive types`.

So, if you have code

```
val f: Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Apple]]]] = new Apple
```

Only then will the compiler require to "think" about this type `Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Apple]]]]` and it's comparision with type `Apple`.

It will then be able to generate evidence `Apple <:< Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Fruit[Apple]]]]` by using the type relation `Apple <: Fruit[Apple]` (provided by inheritence) and `Fruit[T2] <: Fruit[T1]` for any `T2 <: T1` (prvided by co-variance of `A` in kind `Fruit[A]`). And thus the above code will successfully `type-check`.

And in case, if this `implicit evidence generation` somehow encounters a loop, it actually will not be an issue because this is already taken care of in implicit resolution/generation rules.

If you look at the implicit resolution rules at https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html, you will find following

> To prevent infinite expansions, such as the magic example above, the compiler keeps track of a stack of “open implicit types” for which implicit arguments are currently being searched. Whenever an implicit argument for type TT is searched, TT is added to the stack paired with the implicit definition which produces it, and whether it was required to satisfy a by-name implicit argument or not. The type is removed from the stack once the search for the implicit argument either definitely fails or succeeds. Everytime a type is about to be added to the stack, it is checked against existing entries which were produced by the same implicit definition and then,
>
> - if it is equivalent to some type which is already on the stack and there is a by-name argument between that entry and the top of the stack. In this case the search for that type succeeds immediately and the implicit argument is compiled as a recursive reference to the found argument. That argument is added as an entry in the synthesized implicit dictionary if it has not already been added.
> - otherwise if the core of the type dominates the core of a type already on the stack, then the implicit expansion is said to diverge and the search for that type fails immediately.
> - otherwise it is added to the stack paired with the implicit definition which produces it. Implicit resolution continues with the implicit arguments of that definition (if any).
>
> Here, the core type of TT is TT with aliases expanded, top-level type annotations and refinements removed, and occurrences of top-level existentially bound variables replaced by their upper bounds.
>
> A core type TT dominates a type UU if TT is equivalent to UU, or if the top-level type constructors of TT and UU have a common element and TT is more complex than UU and the covering sets of TT and UU are equal.

So, the moment Scala compiler finds a loop in implicit constrant search, it will choose that constraint and avoid going into infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the massive effort here. Really appreciated. Taking my time to carefully study every bit of the answer, before a reply and or simply acceptance, but a thumb up already added, based on what i have red so far :)

Comment: Amazing detail explanation. Many  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking in terms of recursion perhaps looking at it purely from the perspective of quantification and bounds might help. For example let's interpret

```
trait Container[A]
```

as saying

```
trait Container[A >: Nothing <: Any]
```

that is, type constructor `Container` accepts all types `A` as argument. Since it takes **all** types, then it will also take our yet-to-be-defined type `Contained`, as whatever we define it must end up somewhere between `Nothing`  and `Any`, hence, without thinking about recursion, we can admit the following is legal

```
trait Contained extends Container[Contained]
```

Next let's just tighten one of the bounds such that

```
trait Container[A <: Container[A]]
```

is interpreted as

```
trait Container[A >: Nothing <: Container[A]]
```

that is, type constructor `Container` accepts all types `A` between `Nothing` and `Container[A]` as argument. Now our yet-to-be-defined type `A = Contained` will indeed end up as a subtype of `Container[A]` since that is what we explicitly tell the compiler with

```
trait Contained extends Container[Contained]
```

so without thinking about recursion too much we can admit above is legal.

---

As a side note, regarding term "recursive type", as with many terms in computer science, I doubt there is a universally accepted definition what exactly it means. For example, paper [F-Bounded Polymorphism for Object-Oriented Programming](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exyfeng/teaching/FOPL/lectureNotes/CookFBound89.pdf) calls

```
class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double) {
  def move(t: (Double, Double)): Point
  def equal(p: Point): Boolean
}
```

a "recursive type" because `Point` declares computations that take and return `Point` values.

Comment: Just to remark that the paper cited is the seminal work on F-bounded polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I look at it:

1. First you're creating a type function `Container[_]` which can be applied to any type `A`. Note that `A` and `Container[A]` are two different types.
2. Next you're creating a new type `Contained`. At this point `Contained` is just a label.
3. Finally, you're telling Scala that `Contained` will extend another type: `Container[Contained]`.

Using `extends` has several consequences, for example:

- You get an automatic conversion `Contained => Container[Contained]` for free