Generic function output for covariance type is wrong, is it a type system bug or expected?
Consider
trait Fruit { 
  val name: String
}
case class Apple(override val name: String) extends Fruit
case class Banana(override val name: String) extends Fruit


When I define a function to collect only specific types
def onlyT[T](list: List[Fruit]): List[T] = list.collect { { case x: T => x } }
def onlyT2[T: ClassTag](list: List[Fruit]): List[T] = list.collect { { case x: T => x } }
val fruitList: List[Fruit] = List(Apple("app1"), Apple("app2"), Apple("app3"), Apple("app4"), Banana("ban1"), Banana("ban2"), Banana("ban3"))

And below val a is of type List[Banana] but contains entries of type Apple.
val a: List[Banana] = onlyT[Banana](fruitList)
val b: List[Banana] = fruitList.collect { case x: Banana => x }
val c: List[Banana] = onlyT2[Banana](fruitList)
println(a) // List(Apple(app1), Apple(app2), Apple(app3), Apple(app4), Banana(ban1), Banana(ban2), Banana(ban3))
println(b) // List(Banana(ban1), Banana(ban2), Banana(ban3))
println(c) // List(Banana(ban1), Banana(ban2), Banana(ban3))

Is this expected? Or is it a typesystem bug? I know at runtime type is erased, but not sure why it works for b but not a? I think the compiler should not allow a if it will be like this. Anything I am missing?
FYI, this is not a question to solve the issue I can resolve it by using ClassTag. The question is: Why is scala compiler allowing the type declaration val a: List[Banana] and we end up with a list of apples and bananas of type List[Banana]

This question has also been posted to https://users.scala-lang.org/t/generic-function-output-for-covariance-type-is-wrong-is-it-a-type-system-bug-or-expected/10281 and there is discussion there.

This behavior is a consequence of type erasure.
So... In Java any F[T] is simplified to F[Object] at runtime.
Similarly your method
def onlyT[T](list: List[Fruit]): List[T] = 
  list.collect { { case x: T => x } }

is actually simplified to
def onlyT(list: List[Fruit]): List[Object] = 
  list.collect { { case x: Object => x } }

Which is why everything passes the filter when you call onlyT[Banana](fruitList).
No such type erasure occurs in case of fruitList.collect { case x: Banana => x }.

Thanks for the response, but the question asked is not why collect passes all elements (due to type erasure), this is expected to happen; rather question is scala compiler allowing the type declaration val a: List[Banana] and we ending up with a list of apples and bananas of type List[Banana]. Updated the question description to clarify this

@fineThanksAndYou I think the question is answered, it's due to type erasure that does happen in the case of using generics in onlyT but not in the case of collect.

@user2609980 I don't think so, we end up with a value of type List[Banana] that has elements that are Apples. I believe this breaks the type system, it acts as if this is a dynamically typed language.

@fineThanksAndYou type erasure does break the type system yes in this case, as explained in this answer.

@user2609980 thanks I mark this accepted answer now

@fineThanksAndYou It is not breaking the type system at all. Types do not really exist at runtime. Only classes do. The compiler uses the class information to add validations which emulates the type guaruntees expressed by us in our code. All of this works very well with any defined types. Something like List is not a type. It is a kind. List[Banana] is a type with a corresponding class to it.

To make onlyT work, it will need to have validations for every possible class for List[T]. But while compiling List[T]. Java/Scala can not afford to generate all possible classes for a List[T] where T can be anything. It is not just a question of affordability. It is also not possible. Imagine method onlyT can be part of a library which can be used by anyone for any type T defined by them. The Java/Scala compiler can not know which all T does this method is going to be used with. So... it can not add all the desnsive validations. Hence it does the best possible thing it can do.

As there is no type bound on T. It adds a class validation to check for Object. If you had any type bound like T <: Fruit, it would have used Fruit instead of Object. Where as in case of b. You are directly putting x: Banana, so there is no unknowns or infinite possibilities. It can add direct class validations for Banana`.

To read more about kind vs types vs classes, you can refer to my answer about F-bound polymorphism - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239036/1151929
